# Short proof on $\mathbb{Z^\ast_p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Short proof on $\mathbb{Z^\ast_p}$:

Prove for any prime number p, $\mathbb{Z^\ast_p}$ is the set of all the non-zero integers modp forms an abelian group under multiplication.

I'm looking at the proof and it starts off by showing that multiplication is a closed binary operation by saying:

If $\overline{a}, \overline{b} \in \mathbb{Z^\ast_p}$ then $\overline{ab} \in \mathbb{Z^\ast_p}$ since $p | ab \implies p | a$ or $p | b$ I don't understand at all the justification for the proof, could someone explain how "$p | ab \implies p | a$ or $p | b$ " explains anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\overline{ab}$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. Then $\overline{ab}=\overline{0}$, so that $p\mid ab$. Now use the argument.

Answer (score 2):

The only form $\;\overline{ab}\notin\Bbb Z_p^*\;$ is if $\;p\mid ab\;$ , right? But then the prime thing kicks in, and either $\;p\mid a\;$

or $\;p\mid b\;$ , which actually means $\;a\notin\Bbb Z_p^*\;\;or\;\;b\notin\Bbb Z_p^*\;$ ...